# Start me off on how to make a multistep output in Matlab neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series

I am working on a project where I use optical tweezers to trap bacteria or a micron-sized particle on a slide. The electromagnetic properties of the laser trap the particle. I use a spatial light modulator, which has thousands of micron-sized liquid crystal mirrors which shapes the laser by inputting phase mask in Fourier space. A phase mask is a 2D grayscale image in Fourier space. This means that I can use the phase mask to make the laser have the greatest intensity in the center, on a side, or I could make the the greatest laser intensity be shaped like a circle or a cross. The particle will go to the point of maximum intensity.

By using a camera, I would like to track a micron-sized particle, say a silica sphere, and generate the appropriate phase mask. The input will be x and y coordinates, and the algorithm will check the position of bead and will monitor stability; I want the silica sphere to move slowly during the training process while the phase mask is generated.

Here's an example of a phase mask and intensity profile.

[image]

[image]

In preparing for this project, I want to do an exercise where the neural network generates a phase mask from the intensity profile. I will input x and y coordinates, and the program will generate the phase mask by checking the intensity profile. I think this can be done with a Narx network (but if you think there's a better approach please let me know)

```
[X,T] = simplenarx_dataset;
net = narxnet(1:2,1:2,10);
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,{},T);
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net)
```

The net I have right now is

[image]

But I would like the net to be

[image]

Where the intensity is calculated from the phasemask. I would like to know how to make a neural net with the form of my roughly photoshopped image above.

Thank you!

Comment: why did you go for a narxnet (like why the autoregressive part)? i am not that into lasers but i feel like the previous position is not really important for the outcome. do you just need a neural net that has as input [x,y,intensity] and get 1 numeric output out of those inputs? how does you data look like and can you post some data examples in your question please? ( thats important if you dont know how to prepare the data for the net)

Comment: just a view thoughts here: narxnet is for timeseries forecasts (where the last value is important to the next-in your example the 1:2 says take the last 2 values in account) How about a input-output-net? getting the net to train with intensity data, created from the phasemask output is quite difficult. can you create the inverse function of the phasemask->intensity callculation? In what format is the data you want to use for training?

Comment: oh I can't invert the intensity. When we find the intensity, we square the real part of the electric field, but the phase requires the imaginary part, so we lose the information. An input-output-net with time dependence sounds good. It's okay that training the net with intensity data created from the phasemask is difficult, how would I go about doing it? Do I have to code it from scratch or is there a way to do it with the matlab neural network toolbox?

Comment: the nntool is quite powerful and will create most of the code for you, however if you dont get good results from the basic settings you have to read quite a lot of nn stuff to optimize it. i would create the net via toolbox then you have to make your own Output Process Function. look at an ouput of an existing net there is a lot to read about that (net.outputs -> processFcn,Settings,Params)